# Is there checked version of NoSuchElementException

Tags: java

Does well-known checked version of NoSuchElementException exists in standard Java?

My primary motive is clearly communicating method behaviour and so force developer to handle situation where NoSuchElementException is thrown.

Edit:
As answers suggest, NoSuchElementException is Exception, an Error. In my case "Object not found" situation is valid behavior. So with that in mind, I came with another solution, using Optional. It's the most direct way to communicate possibility of returning "Object not found".

Comment: Why don't you create your own?

Comment: The `NoSuchElementException` is a runtime exception because it means **you, the programmer** did something wrong (like calling `next()` without checking `hasNext()`) Checked exceptions are for when there is an error that your program might explicitly have a way to recover from (like prompting for the location of a file when a `FileNotFoundException` has occurred). In this case, if you want a checked exception, you'll need to write your own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no standard direct checked equivalent for this exception.

> My primary motive is clearly communicating method behavior ...

The real question what "behavior" you are trying to convey.

- If you want to convey the complete meaning of `NoSuchElementException`, then there isn't one *by definition*.  The complete meaning includes the possible contexts where the exceptions will be thrown, and clearly any "alternative" exception won't be thrown by various standard classes that throw `NoSuchElementException`.
- But if you just want a roughly equivalent meaning, there are some possible candidates: see [Is there a standard java exception class that means "The object was not found"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24760314/is-there-a-standard-java-exception-class-that-means-the-object-was-not-found).  Or you could simply define a custom (checked) exception.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is.

That said, you should think twice before throwing a checked exception.
The standard usage for checked exceptions is to signal abnormal conditions that are out of the caller's control, such as:

- trying to open a non-existent file
- trying to use a failed/dropped network connection

The rationale being that *if the caller can prevent the abnormal condition, it shouldn't be forced to handle it*.

You can find more info in the classic [Effective Java book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0134685997) (the 3rd edition just came out, btw), especially Item 71 ("Avoid unnecessary use of checked exceptions").