# Which exception to throw if array list doesnt have the object that's passed in?

Tags: java

I have a question on what exception to throw when the passed in object is not in an array list.

```
public void deleteReview(Review review) {
    if(!reviews.contains(review)) {
        throw exception here..
    }

    reviews.remove(review);
}
```

Comment: Anything you want/need...

Comment: who says you need to throw an Exception?

Comment: Sounds more business case, I guess you can handle it without Exception as-well with specific conditions.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24760314

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should :

- Create your own `Exception` : [`How to create custom exceptions in Java ?`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1754315/how-to-create-custom-exceptions-in-java#answers)
- Use [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) : *Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an illegal or inappropriate argument.*
- Use [`NoSuchElementException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/NoSuchElementException.html) : *Thrown by various accessor methods to indicate that the element being requested does not exist.*

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a business case. 
Its not really a case for an exception. It just wasn't found. You can just ignore the case.

However, if you really want to throw an exception, you could try NoSuchElementException or even better create your own class that extends Exception and throw that.

Comment: this seems more like a comment than an answer